# como repetir este comando iimplay sem parar

Tags: javascript, macro

```
iimPlay ("Pixel Coin Bot.iim");
iimPlay ("claim.iim");
iimPlay ("wait.iim");
```

Eu tenho este comando mais quero que ele fique executando este 3 macros
sem parar como fazer isso.

Comment: De onde vem esse código? Não identifiquei a linguagem.

Comment: eu uso este código em No Imacro  para firefox com extenção .js ele executa 3 macros mais faz iso apenas 1 vez

Comment: Mas o que esse comando faz? Aparentemente ele está chamando outros 3 scripts.

Comment: eu tenho 3 macros ai eu uso o script js para executar cada macro 1 de cada vez mais ele executa apenas 1 vez cada macro queria que o js executa-se os macros mais de uma vez  tipo quando

Comment: imacro aceita js, talvez seja mais facil alguem te ajudar por javascript. Eu mesmo não identifiquei que linguagem é essa ai que usa `iimPlay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem como os colegas não entendi qual a utilidade dessa linguagem ou em que contexto ela entra ... porém se ela tem alguma similaridade com JavaScript o jeito mais fácil de dar loop infinito seria usando "for" ou "while" ... algo como:

```
for (;;) {
 iimPlay ("Pixel Coin Bot.iim");
 iimPlay ("claim.iim");
 iimPlay ("wait.iim");
}
```

OU

```
while (true) {
 iimPlay ("Pixel Coin Bot.iim");
 iimPlay ("claim.iim");
 iimPlay ("wait.iim");
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda o código esta funcionando mais quando clico parar no imacros do firefox ele não para poderia me dizer com ficaria o código definindo um quantidade pra script ser executado invez de fica infinito

Comment: Bem no caso do "for" basta definir a quantidade de vezes que ela ir correr assim: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {` nesse caso ele irá correr 10x.